# undefined reference to symbol 'timer_settime@@GLIBC_2.3.3

Tags: linux, qemu

OS: Linux

I am trying to link `mips64-softmmu/qemu-system-mips64` but it results into error:

```
./slirp/misc.o: In function `memset':
/usr/include/bits/string3.h:81: warning: memset used with constant zero length parameter; 
this could be due to transposed parameters
/usr/bin/ld: ../qemu-timer.o: undefined reference to symbol 'timer_settime@@GLIBC_2.3.3'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'timer_settime@@GLIBC_2.3.3' is defined in DSO /lib64/librt.so.1 so   try adding it to the linker command line

/lib64/librt.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [qemu-system-mips64] Error 1
make: *** [subdir-mips64-softmmu] Error 2
```

Can anyone suggest me how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is solved by editing two files, `Makefile` and `Makefile.target` by adding

`LIBS+=-lz -lrt -lm`

Answer (score 13):

This problem occurs because rt library doesn't link.

Edit Makefile.target in your qemu directory, find `LIBS+=-lz`, add `LIBS+=-lrt` beneath this line.

Or say, added following patch locally

```
--- a/tools/qemu-xen/Makefile.target    2013-04-05 23:39:54.000000000 +0000
+++ b/tools/qemu-xen/Makefile.target    2013-04-25 13:54:59.360000000 +0000
@@ -206,6 +206,7 @@
obj-$(CONFIG_NO_KVM) += kvm-stub.o
obj-y += memory.o
LIBS+=-lz
+LIBS+=-lrt

QEMU_CFLAGS += $(VNC_TLS_CFLAGS)
QEMU_CFLAGS += $(VNC_SASL_CFLAGS)
```