# Interfacing Haskell and C++

Tags: c++, haskell, g++, ghc

I'd like to call some Haskell functions in a c++ program.

In order to do so, i have applied [these](https://github.com/jarrett/cpphs)
 instructions and adapted them to my code and system.

What I have for the moment is the following:

- Main.cpp
- Shared header and cpp files
- makefile
- cpp/

  - some cpp and header files
- haskell/

  - hello.hs

The make file is the following:

```
CPP_SOURCES = main.cpp textures.cpp cpp/game.cpp \
cpp/piece.cpp cpp/factories.cpp cpp/utils.cpp
HASKELL_SOURCES = haskell/hello.hs

all: main; ./main

main: $(CPP_SOURCES) HaskellPart.o; g++ \
    -lsfml-graphics \
    -lsfml-window \
    -lsfml-system \
    -I/usr/lib/ghc/include \
    -liconv \
    -I/usr/lib/ghc/ghc-8.0.1/include \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/ghc-8.0.1 \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/rts \
    -lHSrts \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/base-4.9.0.0 \
    -lHSbase-4.9.0.0 \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0 \
    -lHSghc-prim-0.5.0.0 \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1 \
    -lHSinteger-gmp-1.0.0.1 \
    -lHSghc-prim-0.5.0.0 \
    -fno-stack-protector \
    -Wall \
    -o main $(CPP_SOURCES) haskell/hello.o

HaskellPart.o: $(HASKELL_SOURCES); ghc -fforce-recomp -fPIC $(HASKELL_SOURCES)

clean: ; rm -rf main && rm -rf haskell/*.o && \
rm -rf haskell/*.hi && rm -rf haskell/*_stub.h
```

What I have done is:

1. add `-I/usr/lib/ghc/include` to allow g++ to find `HsFFI.h`
2. update the librairies paths
3. add `-fPIC` to the ghc arguments to avoid symbol errors.

However, I end up with the following output:

```
    $ make
ghc -fforce-recomp -fPIC haskell/hello.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Hello            ( haskell/hello.hs, haskell/hello.o )
g++ \
-lsfml-graphics \
-lsfml-window \
-lsfml-system \
-I/usr/lib/ghc/include \
 -liconv \
-L/usr/lib/ghc/rts \
-lHSrts \
-L/usr/lib/ghc/base-4.9.0.0 \
-lHSbase-4.9.0.0 \
-L/usr/lib/ghc/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0 \
-lHSghc-prim-0.5.0.0 \
-L/usr/lib/ghc/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1 \
-lHSinteger-gmp-1.0.0.1 \
-lHSghc-prim-0.5.0.0 \
 -fno-stack-protector \
 -Wall \
 -o main main.cpp textures.cpp cpp/game.cpp cpp/piece.cpp cpp/factories.cpp cpp/utils.cpp haskell/hello.o
/tmp/ccHPRuDY.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x358): undefined reference to `hs_init'
main.cpp:(.text+0x375): undefined reference to `hs_exit'
haskell/hello.o: In function `sRs_info':
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `newCAF'
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `stg_bh_upd_frame_info'
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `ghczmprim_GHCziCString_unpackCStringzh_closure'
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `stg_ap_n_fast'
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `newCAF'
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `stg_bh_upd_frame_info'
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `base_SystemziIO_putStrLn_closure'
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `stg_ap_p_fast'
haskell/hello.o: In function `helloFromHaskell':
(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `rts_lock'
haskell/hello.o: In function `helloFromHaskell':
(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `base_GHCziTopHandler_runIO_closure'
haskell/hello.o: In function `helloFromHaskell':
(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `rts_apply'
haskell/hello.o: In function `helloFromHaskell':
(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `rts_evalIO'
haskell/hello.o: In function `helloFromHaskell':
(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `rts_checkSchedStatus'
haskell/hello.o: In function `helloFromHaskell':
(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `rts_unlock'
haskell/hello.o: In function `stginit_export_Hello_zdfstableZZC0ZZCmainZZCHelloZZChelloFromHaskell':
ghc_3.c:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `foreignExportStablePtr'
haskell/hello.o: In function `sRs_closure':
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.data+0x40): undefined reference to `stg_IND_STATIC_info'
haskell/hello.o: In function `rHM_closure':
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.data+0x60): undefined reference to `ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_TrNameS_static_info'
haskell/hello.o: In function `rI0_closure':
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.data+0x70): undefined reference to `ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_TrNameS_static_info'
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.data+0x80): undefined reference to `ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Module_static_info'
haskell/hello.o: In function `SRD_srt':
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x0): undefined reference to `ghczmprim_GHCziCString_unpackCStringzh_closure'
/tmp/ghc9fcb_0/ghc_7.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x8): undefined reference to `base_SystemziIO_putStrLn_closure'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:17: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Thank you!

**EDIT :**

According to n.m answer, I changed the order of g++ arguments. Here's the new makefile:

```
CPP_SOURCES = main.cpp textures.cpp cpp/game.cpp cpp/piece.cpp cpp/factories.cpp cpp/utils.cpp
HASKELL_SOURCES = haskell/hello.hs
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -fno-stack-protector

all: main; ./main

main: $(CPP_SOURCES) HaskellPart.o; g++ \
    $(CFLAGS) -o main $(CPP_SOURCES) haskell/hello.o \
    -lsfml-graphics \
    -lsfml-window \
    -lsfml-system \
    -I/usr/lib/ghc/include \
    -liconv \
    -I/usr/lib/ghc/ghc-8.0.1/include \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/ghc-8.0.1 \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/base-4.9.0.0 \
    -lHSbase-4.9.0.0 \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0 \
    -lHSghc-prim-0.5.0.0 \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1 \
    -lHSinteger-gmp-1.0.0.1 \
    -lHSghc-prim-0.5.0.0 \
    -L/usr/lib/ghc/rts \
    -lHSrts \

HaskellPart.o: $(HASKELL_SOURCES); ghc -fforce-recomp -fPIC $(HASKELL_SOURCES)

clean: ; rm -rf main && rm -rf haskell/*.o && rm -rf haskell/*.hi && rm -rf haskell/*_stub.h
```

But it raised another error:

`/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/ghc/rts/libHSrts.a(Itimer.o): undefined reference to symbol 'timer_settime@@GLIBC_2.3.3'`

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286738/undefined-reference-to-symbol-timer-settimeglibc-2-3-3) thread, I added `-lrt` but got:

`/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/ghc/rts/libHSrts.a(Linker.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5'`

So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557683/undefined-reference-to-symbol-dlsymglibc-2-4) thread I added `-ldl` and now it's [a big mess...](http://pastebin.com/XQhy0KMf)

**EDIT : BOUNTY**

Guys I'm adding a bounty spending a large proportion of my low amount of reputation because I can't manage to make this work and really need this.

This is for a school related project but I have to precise that this is not cheating as subject only says: "write a large program in c++ and write the same program in haskell".

Making a common graphical interface for both programs is my decision and is out of the scope of the coursework.

Beside that, I think there a lack of documentation on this subject on internet, my teacher told me he never managed to do it so it would be helpful to have a constructed answer on the configuration of g++ with Haskell Foreign Export.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: You have removed the last -lHSghc-prim-x.y.z parameter. Please consider restoring it, despite having another -lHSghc-prim-x.y.z upper in the list.

Comment: Done. I edited my post with the new output, but it look identical. Thanks

Comment: Just noticed you have all the libraries before all the objects/source files in your compilation command. **This is wrong and won't work**. See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc). I also think you need to move HSrts down the chain of libraries in the link line. It probably should be the last library in the list.

Comment: If you really need this to work, I highly recommend you write a C wrapper of the functions you really need. Then, it is relatively easier to call Haskell from C and then C++ from C (there will be more examples online of the former, and the latter it not. very difficult).

Comment: @alec Using C would introduce a third language and I'm not allowed to. Moreover, it must be possible to achieve what I want by compiling Haskell and c++ together. I can't believe that it hasn't been done. I'm sure having a constructed answer on this thread would help others.

Comment: @MaximeVAST This sort of thing tends to get hairy (source: I did this a couple months ago with Haskell/Java). Perhaps you would be willing to rephrase your question? Right now, you don't really have an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would maybe be a good idea to include a minimal Haskell/C++ program that isn't working - that way we have _something_ to try to fix. Right now, you are the only person who can iterate.

Comment: @alec. Got it ! here's the MVCE question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100934/calling-haskell-from-c)

Comment: Link to my answer on your second version of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43107962/7720738

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried just linking to my answer on your other version of this question but it decided to automatically make it a comment... Not particularly helpful because people who find this thread in the future might just see it as unanswered so I'll paste the full answer instead.

Not sure whether that's actually in your file or whether it's just in the version you put in your question but "// hello.hs" won't compile. Comments are -- in Haskell not //.

Anyway on to the interesting part...

First you need to import the HsFFI.h header file into your C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Hello_stub.h"
#include <HsFFI.h>
```

Then use ghc to link the files after compiling them. Open a command prompt / terminal and navigate the directory containing your C++ and Haskell files. Then run the following commands:

```
ghc -c -XForeignFunctionInterface -O hello.hs
g++ -c -O main.cpp -I "C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\include"                         
ghc -no-hs-main hello.o main.o -lstdc++
```

The filepath in the second command is to the directory containing the HsFFI.h file.

Running main then outputs:

```
Hello from C++
Hello from Haskell
```